# Django Model Fields Indexing

Tags: django, indexing, django-models

I only know that indexing is helpful and it queries faster.

What is the difference between following two?

**1.**

```
class Meta:
       indexes = [
           models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name',]),
           models.Index(fields=['-date_of_birth',]),
]
```

**2.**

```
class Meta:
       indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['first_name',]),
            models.Index(fields=['last_name',]),
            models.Index(fields=['-date_of_birth',]),
]
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**Example 1:**

The first example creates a single index on the `last_name` and `first_name` field.

```
indexes = [
   models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name',]),
]
```

It will be useful if you search on the last name and first name together, or the last name by itself (because `last_name` is the first field in the index).

```
MyModel.objects.filter(last_name=last_name, first_name=first_name)
MyModel.objects.filter(last_name=last_name)
```

However, it will not be useful for searching for the `first_name` by itself (because `first_name` is not the first field in the index).

```
MyModel.objects.filter(first_name=first_name)  # not useful
```

**Example 2:**

The second example creates an index for the `first_name` field and a separate index for the `last_name` field.

```
indexes = [
    models.Index(fields=['first_name',]),
    models.Index(fields=['last_name',]),
]
```

It will be useful if you do lookups based on first name or last name in your code

```
MyModel.objects.filter(first_name=search)
MyModel.objects.filter(last_name=search)
```

Comment: @Daviid One index of both fields would be fastest in theory, but one or two separate indexes might be fast enough in practice. Use `explain` to see how your database is using the indexes, and benchmark to see whether indexing the fields together is worth it.

Answer (score 6):

Django Model Index was introduced in Django 1.11

**what is Model.indexes:**

By default, indexes are created with an ascending order for each column. To define an index with a descending order for a column, add a hyphen before the field’s name.

For your query,
 `models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name','-date_of_birth',]),` would create SQL with `(last_name, first_name, date_of_birth DESC).`

**Lets move to your question,**

you asked difference between 2 queries,

both will take `models.Index(fields=['-date_of_birth',]),`

because least one will override the assigned variables. from your question least is `dateofbirth` so it will override above two lines.

**so as per documentation preferable method is,**
because indexing field should be in single list.. so django will prepare SQL indexing from list of fields...

```
models.Index(fields=['last_name', 'first_name', '-date_of_birth']),
```

Comment: Your suggestion will create a single index - that won't be useful if the OP wants to query on first name or date of birth alone.

Comment: Does it make sense to index the ID field?

Comment: @alias51 depending on the DB you're using, this is done automatically for any field by which primary_key=True. If you use Django's 'auto' stuff, PostgreSQL will do this for you automatically - if you for example override 'id' with a uuid field and give if the primary_key=True attr, it will also be done automatically for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Django Model Fields Indexing Example for Book model, It will be helpful to implement:**

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    publication_year = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['author', 'publication_year'], name='author_pub_year_idx'),
            models.Index(fields=['title'], name='title_idx'),
        ]
```