# Faster way to find latest entry for a given period in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've got a basic event model with the following fields:

- time_stamp
- key
- description

I need to return the latest value of description for a given key prior to a given date. Under normal conditions I would use the following query:

```
desc = Event.objects.filter(key=key,time_stamp__lte=date).order_by('-id').values_list('description',flat=True)[0]
```

However in this case the model has 2.5 million records, so it takes about 15 seconds to execute. I managed to get a small improvement in speed by specifying a time_stamp__range, but that limits how far back the latest entry can be which I don't really want.

I've done some testing and the **order_by('-id')** is what's slowing it down.

I'm considering splitting the event model into models for types of event keys. This will decrease the number of records per model, but before I go that route, can anybody perhaps recommend a faster way of get the last record of a query-set?

Comment: "*order_by('-id') is what's slowing it down."*, Then probably you have set the default ordering in ascending order, make it reverse may help you

Comment: I've tested setting the ordering in the model meta, but that produces the same SQL query as when I set the ordering on the filter, so unfortunately it does not improve performance.

Comment: does removing the `values_list()` help at all? could you do:
`Event.objects.filter(key=key,time_stamp__lte=date).order_by('-id').first().description`

Comment: Using values_list returns only the required columns so it's slightly faster, but I tested your suggestion and it produces the same SQL apart from the columns returned. Basically everything I've tried produces a SQL query ending with `...ORDER BY 'event'.'id' DESC  LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with db index

[Model index reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/indexes)

```
from django.db import models    

class Event():
    key = ...
    time_stamp = ...

    class Meta:
        index = [
            models.Index(fields=['key', '-time_stamp']),

    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it, but unfortunately it does not seem to make a difference. Apparently MySQL doesn't support reversed indexes for some reason. From the Django docs you linked: **For example Index(fields=['headline', '-pub_date']) would create SQL with (headline, pub_date DESC). Index ordering isn’t supported on MySQL. In that case, a descending index is created as a normal index.**

Comment: I checked again and saw that I only included the '-time_stamp' in my original testing of the indexes. After adding the other fields to the index and reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328826/django-model-fields-indexing) on the importance of the order in which the indexes are defined I'm very happy to report that the query time dropped to under a second! Thanks very much.